# I have two values on the first row of the table it_courses field course_branch. When i join branch table with it_courses table result only one value

Tags: php, mysql

[these are the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h6wM.jpg)

[and it results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9AXe.jpg)
I have two values on the first row of the table it_courses field course_branch. When i join branch table with it_courses table result is like this.it doesnt shows the second value in the 1st row that was entered in the it_coursestable

> Query :

```
SELECT branch.branch_name
FROM `branch`
JOIN `it_courses` ON it_courses.course_branch = branch.branch_id
```

Comment: Please make your table structure perfect afterwards you can get output accurate.

Comment: what do u mean by accurate.how should i make it perfect.do u have any suggestions...... @NikuNj Rathod

Comment: it is because course_branch is not branch_id it is branch_name.

Comment: Do you have a question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this database structure and query :

> Table:

tbl_it_courses (id - PK, cource_name, branch_id - FK)

tbl_branch (id - PK, branch_id, branch_name)

> Table : tbl_it_courses

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_it_courses (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cource_name VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    branch_id VARCHAR(70) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO `tbl_it_courses` (`Id`, `cource_name`, `branch_id`) VALUES (NULL, 'PHP', '1,4'),(NULL, '.NET', '3'), (NULL, 'CCNA', '3');
```

> Table : tbl_branch

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_branch (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    branch_id VARCHAR(70) DEFAULT NULL,
    branch_name VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO `tbl_branch` (`Id`, `branch_id`, `branch_name`) VALUES (NULL, 'Ern', 'brn92b224'),(NULL, 'Klm', 'brnaf3650'), (NULL, 'Tvm', 'brn272493');
```

> Query :

```
SELECT tbl_it_courses.cource_name, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_branch.branch_name) FROM tbl_branch WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tbl_branch.id,tbl_it_courses.branch_id) > 0)  as branch_name
FROM tbl_it_courses
```

I Hope It will Help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT branch.branch_id,it_courses.course_name
FROM `branch`
left JOIN `it_courses` ON LOCATE(branch.branch_name,it_courses.course_branch) > 0
```